# What operating systems use both a Render thread and a UI thread?

Tags: architecture, multithreading

Microsoft employees commonly describe Windows 8 as having both a Render thread and UI thread.

[Typically they say](https://web.archive.org/web/20151018071648/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/05/tackling-performance-killers-common-performance-problems-with-metro-style-apps.aspx) the Render thread performs animations and the UI thread handles most other operations: parsing, layout, applying templates, data binding, input processing, most app callbacks, etc.

> Animations can be calculated from beginning to end when they are created. Sometimes the changes to the property being animated don’t affect rest of the objects in a scene. These are called independent animations and they are run on the **composition thread instead of the UI thread**. This guarantees that they remain smooth because the composition thread is updated at a consistent cadence...

Is this a common architecture or unique to Windows 8? What about Windows Phone 8? Android? iOS?

Comment: BeOS did something like that, but I don't remember the specifics.  Made it very responsive on older hardware.

Answer (score 1):

[AmigaDOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaDOS) did, which is why you still find Amigas running small TV station text feeds.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Comment: Well, frankly, it's a poor question, asking simply for exemplars of OSes that do this.  So the answer is appropriate, albeit short.

Comment: the link you refer to says nothing about UI / Render threads, how would readers tell if your answer is correct or not? Agree that the question is poor (quite a pity that my close vote on it has expired), but frankly, your answer looks even worse